# Can't find where scheduled task is set

Tags: bash, cron

I have a production server running a scheduled task that I simply can't track down.

It seems that it is running `dbdump.bash` on a daily basis, but none of the cron files have a reference to that or anything running a back up!

I've tried to `grep -r "dbdump.bash" /` to search for the offending job, but no luck so far. The backups are large, and if not manually removed will completely fill up the hard drive.

How can I track this down? Thanks!

**Update**

Here's the contents of `/etc/crontab`:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

**Update: Contents of `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/tweaver`**

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.cb6x6l/crontab installed on Tue Dec 21 20:08:50 2010)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
# m h  dom mon dow   command
5 2 * * * /home/tweaver/dbrefresh/dbdump.bash
```

Comment: I don't see any relevant references in either - which files are important in `/etc/init.d/`?

Comment: Issue `crontab -l` to see the list of jobs for current user and `sudo crontab -l -u user` to see jobs of other users.

Comment: Look into the `/etc/cron.*/` directories.

Comment: Yes, look also `/etc/crontab` file and `/etc/cron.*` directories

Comment: @Rinzwind he said "it seems" ;)

Comment: This is an SQL-backup script. Where is the script located?

Comment: The script is located in a previous admin's home directory: `/home/tweaver/dbrefresh/dbdump.bash`

Comment: Look also in /var/spool/cron/crontabs. Maybe this script is launched by a user crontab file.

Comment: If you want to stop the job, rename the script file since you know where it is.

Comment: **FOUND IT!** It was hiding deep inside `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` under the user's name.

Comment: I updated with the contents of the file; it has a warning not to edit it. Is there somewhere else I should be removing it from?

Comment: ha! @EricCarvalho gratz. make it an answer and then we can clean this up _O-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user run `crontab -e` to create a personal cron job a file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>` is created.

Just remove the file with the same name of user who created that cron job and you're done:

```
sudo rm /var/spool/cron/crontabs/tweaver
```

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e`

will edit that master file, don't edit /var/spool/cron/crontabs/tweaver manually, just do the above.

Comment: In this case, `tweaver` is not my user, and I don't have his password. It's an old student project that some students have long since left behind, so it's now my job to clean up the leftovers!